# Iterating through a tuple using a function and *args

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function using *args. It should take in certain numbers and then output the products of the numbers multiplied by 10.

I'm learning to use *args but I'm having trouble getting the output. My result only outputs the first number in the function. I've tried using a for loop, thinking it would iterate over each character, but it didn't work.

```
def myfunc(*args):
for args1 in args:
    return args1*10
```

When I run the function:

```
myfunc(10.1,20)
```

The expected output should be

```
(101.0,200.0)
```

The actual output is

```
(101.0)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, that's what you need:

```py
def myfunc(*args): 
    return tuple(map(lambda x: x*10, args))
```

`*args` can be retrieved in the function as a list called `args`. What you do here is just multiplying the first element by 10 and return it, so the function stops.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `yield` instead of `return`, to make your function return a generator, which can then be converted to `tuple` whenever you need

```
>>> def myfunc(*args):
...     for args1 in args:
...         yield args1*10
... 
>>> 
>>> myfunc(10.1,20)
<generator object myfunc at 0x7f20d1ae8ad0>
>>> 
>>> tuple(myfunc(10.1,20))
(101.0, 200)
```